# Where can I find a dataset that lists all the businesses and their addresses operating in a given city?

Tags: data-request, city, business

At one point I had an idea for a localized web site specifically focusing on a single city. I spoke to several people within that city's government, and it was clear that there was no one single place that kept easily accessible and update-to-date contact information on all the businesses legally operating in the city limits. The closest I came was the chamber of commerce listed all members on their Web site, but these were members only.

Answer (score 4):

I would look into [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) for this. You have to register for an API key and the quota is limited to 100,000 requests a day (plus some multipliers on some requests), but it's a rather verbose database.

Example:

Here is a request URL to get all "food" places within 500m of the specified latitude-longitude that has the word "harbour" in it:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

The response is JSON so you will need to do a little parsing unless you use their JavaScript API or use some other wrapper.

If you're using Java, I actually developed my own Java wrapper around this API which I believe successfully maps the API 1 to 1 if it fits your purposes: https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java

With this library you can just do something like:

```
GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlaces("apiKey");
List<Place> places = client.getNearbyPlaces(lat, lng, radius, GooglePlaces.MAXIMUM_RESULTS);
for (Place place : places) {
    System.out.println(place.getName());
    System.out.println(place.getAddress());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the Google place Data are under copyright license

Answer (score 2):

If the city or county has an open portal it is likely they will have a business license dataset. Otherwise, I would contact the "Revenue/Licensing" department for the City and request a copy in electronic format.

I have a catalog of government open data portals at this link. There are 38 US Cities in the list:

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/opendata.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use the search endpoints of foursquare api to get contact details of the venues from [foursquare search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search).

Comment: Could you provide more detail on how to use Foursquare to get contact info of only legally-operating businesses?

Comment: You can use the search endpoints of foursquare api to get contact details of the venues - https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search